# li breadcrumb image positioning error

Tags: html, css

I've got the following menu.

```
<ul>
<li><img src="images/item_grp_nav_img.jpg" alt="nav-image">Home</li>
<li>Menu Type</li>
<li>Menu Type</li>
<li>Menu Type</li>
</ul>
```

The Css goes as following.

```
#item-group-navigation{
height: 30px;
background-color:#949698;
min-width:760px;
}

#item-group-navigation ul{
height: 100%;
width: 30%;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
margin: 0px;
}

#item-group-navigation li{
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: block;
padding: 3px 6px 0px 5px;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
font-family:MyriadProReg;
}

#item-group-navigation li:first-child:before{
content:none;
}

#item-group-navigation li:before{
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
content: url('../images/list_arrow.jpg');
float: left;
}

#item-group-navigation img{
float: left;
}
```

The issue is displayed on the following image.

[image: Issue]

How Can I fix this issue using my CSS. Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue! I've defined a height & a width where it shouldn't be! 
Thanks to any one who's going through it!

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width `#item-group-navigation ul` .

Comment: removing did it too! :) Thanks any way!